# Create a recursive function that solves this equation

Tags: java

Create a recursive function that solves this equation iteratively:
2x3 – 10x  +4 = 0. And here is the solution, i don't understand why do I get the result 2 when I pass value of 1 and 0.40400000 when I pass value of 0 to method solve(). How does it work?

```
public static double solve(double x)
{
    double y = 2*x*x*x - 10*x + 4;
    if (y > -0.01 && y < 0.01)
        return x;
    else return solve(x + 0.001);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(solve(1));
    // 0.40400000   when starting from 0
    // 2             when starting from 1
}
```

Comment: *`Create a recursive function that solves this equation iteratively`* A bit paradoxical. Also I recommend running this through the debugger to see what is going on "under the hood"

Comment: @GBlodgett the word [*iterative*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_method) here is a math term.

Comment: That's a fair observation, @rustyx, but in fact it *still* does not make much sense to implement an iterative mathematical procedure via a recursive computational algorithm.

Comment: This feels like some of those constants need to be doubles as well. You might be losing some precision. As suggested, a debugger will show you what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what the function does is: it just tests all possible values for `x` in steps of `0.001` until it finds one that satisfies the equation with an error of less than `0.01`.

The function is more or less equivalent to the following, which might be easier to understand:

```
public static double solve(double x) {
    while (true) {                      // repeat...
        double y = 2*x*x*x - 10*x + 4;  // calculate y
        if (-0.01 < y && y < 0.01)      // y close to 0 ?
            return x;                   // "good enough" solution found
        x += 0.001;                     // try next value for x
    }
}
```

Your equation has multiple solutions (see [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%5E3-10x%2B4) for a visualisation), so depending on the starting point, there can be different solutions. You should get another solution of you start with e.g. `x = -3`.

There are, however, several problems with that function. First, it will just run infinitely if you pass an `x` that is larger than the largest `x` that solves the equation, so it might be reasonable to also provide an upper limit for `x`. But it might also miss a solution if the slope is very steep, so it goes from `< -0.01` to `> +0.01` in one step. A better approach might be just to memorize the sign of `y` and see in which step it changes from positive to negative or vice versa, or a combination of the two in case of a minimum or maximum at 0.